# handling .JSON file in Android

Tags: android, json, file

How can I handle JSON response when a webservice returns me .JSON file directly if URL is fired from web browser it downloads a >JSON file?

Comment: I don't understand. Is your problem to read the JSON file or to donwload it from a specific URL ?

Comment: in reading i am converting InputStream to String using BufferedReader readline() there i am doing while((line=br.readLine())1=null) here i get NullPointerException.

Comment: i guess file is not getting downloaded so it is giving this error.

Comment: Check to see if you are able to download the JSON string when you access the web service just use web browser

Comment: using webbrowser i can download the .JSON file but can't view it on webrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//what is this `while((line=br.readLine())1=null)`

```
 if(response!=null){  
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
            int bytes_read = 0;

            while((bytes_read = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0)
            {
                sb.append( new String(buffer,0,bytes_read));
            } 
            System.out.println("Preview image Result=="+sb.toString());
        }
```

Comment: while((line=br.readLine())1=null) is while((line=br.readLine())!=null)

Comment: it also gives NullPointerException